# Powershell wildcard on returns items

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm trying to determine whether the directories under a specified root directory contain files that match a certain pattern, in my case RT*.dcm.

I'm using Powershell 2.0 and I first obtain all sub-directories beneath the specified root directory using

```
$dirList = Get-ChildItem $homeDir -recurse | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'} | Select-Object FullName
```

I then loop through these to see if they contain *.dcm files using  (perhaps there's a better way?)

```
# Find files with a "dcm" extension.
$fileList = Get-ChildItem $dir.fullname | where {$_.extension -eq ".dcm"} | Select-Object FullName 

# Look for directories that contain *.dcm files
if ($fileList.Count -gt 0)  {
    [Console]::WriteLine("Dicom directory: " + $dir.fullname)       
    $dicomDirList += $dir
}
```

The above two sections work ok

I then search through the found directories using

```
foreach($dir in $dicomDirList) {

    $rtFileList = Get-ChildItem $dir | where {$_.name -like "RT*.dcm"} | Select-Object FullName

    foreach($file in $rtFileList) {
        [Console]::WriteLine("RT likey file: " + $file.fullname) 
    }   
}
```

However this doesn't find the files I know that are there?

If I use

```
Get-ChildItem C:\myfolder\RT*.dcm
```

this works, but I can't figure out how to use the returned items from the previous Get-ChildItem call

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be over-complicating things.

To accomplish what `Get-ChildItem C:\myfolder\RT*.dcm` does for the entirety of `$homeDir` (which is what I believe you're trying to do), you can use a single `Get-ChildItem` command:

```
Get-ChildItem $homeDir -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.Name -like "RT*.dcm"}
```

This searches the entirety of `$homeDir` recursively for all of the .dcm files you're looking for and returns them.